# "Multi step" login form in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to create a "Multi step" login form in `Angular 6`, which checks the user name before requesting the password, something like this:

[image]

I would like to change or "redraw" only the content inside of the border.

I've searched and I found the next options:

- Use `ng-switch` directive
- Use `ViewContainerRef` class with `ComponentFactoryResolver`
- Use `angular` material stepper (I did not found any way to hide the icons)

The question is: Which is better? Is there any other way?

If it's possible, I would like to manage the flow in the `parent` component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ViewContainerRef` class with `ComponentFactoryResolver` can be a good solution for what you intend to achieve. It is a more elegant solution in my opinion than `ng-switch` for what you want to achieve.

Basically you would ga as follow:

**LoginModule**

```
    @NgModule({

    declarations: [
        // all your components
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        // components to be loaded at each step
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
    ]
    })export class LoginModule { }
```

**Directive**: you create a directive for the ng-template that will contain the components that need to change at each of login step

```
    @Directive({
      selector: '[appAppsHost]'
    })
    export class AppsHostDirective {
      constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
    }
```

**LoginService**: this service should contain a list with all the components you want to render inside the viewContainerRef, it basically contains a method that returns the proper component:

```
    getAppComponentItem(componentIdentifier: string): AppComponentItem {
        return this.appComponentItems[componentIdentifier];
    }
```

**ContainerComponent**: then comes the last part where you create a container component that is supposed ton contain the component you want:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'login-container',
  templateUrl: './login-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-container.component.scss']
})
export class LoginContainerComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(AppsHostDirective) appAppsHost: AppsHostDirective;

  constructor(
    private readonly componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private readonly loginComponentService: LoginComponentService) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    const viewContainerRef = this.appAppsHost.viewContainerRef;
    const appComponentItem = this.loginComponentService.getAppComponentItem('identifier');
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(appComponentItem.component);
    viewContainerRef.clear();

  }

}
```

For more info, you can read the Angular docs: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader